# Android video upload to server changes rotation 90° without any reason

Tags: java, android, http, video, video-streaming

I have an application that records a video and then uploads it to a server. However, when I try to play the video back, I find that its rotation changes without me doing such a thing. Do you have any idea why this happens ? knowing that when I play the video from the local storage, its rotation is preserved as it was recorded. So, whatever happens, happens during the upload.

Comment: Have you got solution?

Comment: Nope, unfortunately I did not. The issue seems to be Samsung specific(at least according to my tests) and yes, I am still looking for a working example with the solution. Any leads ?